# Python reads tif image differently on Mac and Windows. Why? How? Which is correct? How to fix?

Tags: python, windows, image, macos

I am trying to process some data stored as a tif image.  To my dismay, python 2.7x reads it out differently on my Mac laptop and my Windows workstation.

```
# import modules
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read file
image = plt.imread('fileName.tif')

# display file as image
plt.imshow(image)
```

A visual inspection does not reveal any significant differences, and all notable features in one displayed image are visible in the other.  The same data is indeed being displayed in both cases.  However, a closer look reveals that there are important differences.  The following code returns different results on the two computers:

```
image.shape   # shape & size of the array holding the data
image.dtype   # data type of each element of the array
image[0, 0]   # an individual pixel value
image[1000, 1000]   # another pixel value
image.min()
image.max()
```

On Mac, that code returns

```
(2048, 2048, 4)
dtype('uint8')
array([0, 0, 0, 255], dtype=uint8)
array([71, 71, 71, 255], dtype=uint8)
0
255
```

Whereas on Windows, it returns

```
(2048L, 2048L)
dtype('uint16')
0
78
0
951
```

These differences may seem (mostly) trivial, but I'm working in a context where such details are important.

I initially thought my Mac was interpreting the data correctly.  If so, the slice `image[:, :, n]` is the nth layer in a four-layer image.  On Mac, layers `0`, `1`, and `2` are identical, as the red, green, and blue channels would be in a grayscale image, and layer `3` is all `255`s, as the opacity layer would be in a fully opaque image.

> (Mistakes like this information redundancy are par for the course hereabouts.  The data-taking setups here are cobbled together out of hardware from several different sources by people whose computer literacy often has room for improvement.)

However, an estimate of what the file size ought to be favors Windows.  The size of the file is the same to within 5% on the two computers, at about 8 MB; I put the variation down to some difference in how the information is stored by the two OSs.  We estimate how large it ought to be:

Mac:  4 layers x 4x10^6 pixels per layer x 1 byte per pixel = approx. 16 MB

Windows:  1 layer x 4x10^6 pixels per layer x 2 bytes per pixel = approx. 8 MB

Since Python on Mac is claiming to read twice as much information as the file size indicates, this suggests the Windows version is correct.

So my question is this:  Which of the two readings is correct?  How and why is the same data being read differently?  How can I ensure that similar data is read correctly in the future, regardless of the system my code is run on?

[Link to image file used here.](https://office365stanford-my.sharepoint.com/personal/apf_stanford_edu/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=jsz3eHdMO03ghIo6Mo2vjGVjKQmhr0gv9NgnMe6aaD8%3D&docid=090a8ff60906447eeb716ccf565291990&expiration=2016%2F04%2F24%2018%3A19%3A00)

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have the same versions of Python, numpy, and matplotlib on the two computers?

Comment: Linux and matplotlib 1.3.1 agrees with your Windows result for "sampleImage.tif". The matplotlib plot shows a medium blue circle on a dark blue background. There's a medium blue line extending to approximately (988, 828), where it expands to a circular shape that's covering a false color disc, ranging toward the center from light blue to yellow to red, with the red center mostly covered. Also GIMP can't read the image correctly: "The image you are loading has 16 bits per channel. GIMP can only handle 8 bit, so it will be converted for you. Information will be lost because of this conversion."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very useful `tiffinfo` shows you have a one-channel, 16-bit image:

```
$ tiffinfo sampleImage.tif 
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 34710 (0x8796) encountered.
TIFF Directory at offset 0x8 (8)
  Image Width: 2048 Image Length: 2048
  Resolution: 126.582, 126.582 pixels/cm
  Bits/Sample: 16
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: min-is-black
  Orientation: row 0 top, col 0 lhs
  Rows/Strip: 2048
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  Tag 34710: 1024
```

Tag 34710 contains some camera information and shouldn't affect the result.

vips agrees that pixel (1000, 1000) is indeed 78, and the image maximum is 951.

```
$ vips getpoint sampleImage.tif 1000 1000
78 
$ vips max sampleImage.tif 
951.000000
```

So your Windows install is correct.

On Mac your image has been converted to 8-bit RGBA at some point in processing. You'll need to start checking that the versions of the various bits of software you are using are the same on both machines.